# Creating new swift scene with corresponding sks file

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So i've been playing around with swift for a few weeks now. I've messed around with objective C but i'm more of a java person so applied Objective C is a different ballgame to me. I can successfully create very basic games with simplistic transactions.

I created several scenes that i'm transitioning to which have nodes in them but since I didn't need create actions for those scenes (besides the default gamescene) I didn't even create any sks files for them.

So now i'm finally jumping into creating actions for nodes in a specific swift file and so I created a sks file with the same name as the swift file (I know there's more to it than that in order to link the two together). My question is, how do I link the sks file to the swift file so I can then apply actions and so I can go about and start manipulating nodes programmatically?

I have a scene going to a scene which should theoretically allow me to do certain things if certain nodes are pressed but I can't seem to get anything done in the swift file to correspond to the actual sks file like i've done in the gamescene file or the way I did with view controllers.

Thanks for any help :D!

P.S: I used this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wJu7f9mStg

Comment: you should tag this as 'sprite-kit' so those interested will see it :)

Comment: I only happened on this as I was browsing [swift].. I usually just hang out in [sprite-kit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via initializing a new action.. check `SKAction` documentation (or autocomplete in xcode) to see it's initializers.

Here is a snippet based on Apple's website that will do what you need:

```
// init?(named: String)
// Creates an action of the given name from an action file.
let action = SKAction(named: "whateverYourActionnameIS")
```

Scroll all the way to the bottom to see the list of functions, inits, etc, for SKAction:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction

Comment: You do not use the SKS name, you use the action name.  The SKS file gets loaded automatically. This means you can have 100 actions all in 1 SKS file